The suspicious process is using a lot of CPU time linux
I have a linux server with my projects, docker and postgresql. A few days ago I saw that server's CPU is overloaded. Using the htop I saw that:
The process runned by command /proc/216916/fd/7 us using 97% of my CPU. After killing that process with PID, it runs again with another PID. The directory /proc/{PID} is not exsists.
Are there any solutions other than reinstalling of OS?

are you used command kill -9 PID?
